# How can I add new dependencies to a project for the next developer?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm working on an existing project made with react where before you can run the website, you have to execute `npm install`. For what i understood, inside package.json there is everything your website needs to be right to go. Any dependencies, library used inside the website.

I want to add chakra ui to the project, and from the chakraui website says that i need to execute inside the project folder the command `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion` so  how can i integrate this command, so the other person that will work on this project will execute just `npm install` and have installed chakra ui too?

I asked chatGPT, because cannot find anything online, and that command use npm to install 4 packages

1. @chakra-ui/react
2. @emotion/react
3. @emotion/styled
4. framer-motion

and so i have to open my package.json and add the following line inside

```
{
  "name": "my-react-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My awesome React website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "framer-motion": "^5.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

as you can see under the dependencies and specify the version. chatGPT suggested me that for example, but i wanted the newest so i went on google and search its newest version.

But this feels a little bit.. laborious.
While `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion` take care to install the newest (right?), i have to edit the package.json and specify the version and blabla.

So my question is. What i just did is the correct way, or is there a better way to do it? Or maybe i should have downloaded the package.json file inside the github of chakra ui, so when i run `npm install` npm will see two package.json and will install both of them?

Comment: You couldn't find anything online? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Comment: Protip: Don't use ChatGP. It's likely to steer you wrong on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package.json file is just a list of everything that you installed and that your project needs in order to be launched.

When you execute the **npm install** command it will read the content of package.json and install it inside a node_module folder.

Your command  **npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion**  will do two actions:

1. Install the new package in your node_modules folder
2. Add the new dependency into package.json file so it can be installed again on next npm install

So yes, what you just did is the correct way :)

Comment: ohh, so in reality i should't touch package.json but just use npm. So if i want to install chakra ui, i just run that npm command and npm will set everything for me. If i have problem with dependences, i just have to update the dependecies with npm and so on and in the future, a person will just press npm install.

But all this "way of things" how can i could have learned instead of asking here? Is there a tutorial, a book that talks about this or this is just one of the things that a person will learn while living?

Comment: Yes that's it, you usualy shouldn't touch package.json ! you probably could have lerned this by following a step by step tutorial on how to build a react app. Usualy [openclassroom's](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/7132446-create-a-web-application-with-react-js) tutorial are very good to learn new programming language basics